# File "something" is not recognized as an Arff datafiles

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, weka

The problem is when I try to load a handmade dataset into Weka, I get the aforementioned error.the dataset style is as follows and it seems the style of the dataset has some problems.I've checked correct style of the dataset with "Iris" example but I don't know where the problem is.
Thank you in advance.

```
@RELATION link

@ATTRIBUTE personalinformation  NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE educationalinformation   NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE jobinformation   NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE class    {Strong,Weak}

@DATA
3,5,1,Strong
3,6,3,Strong
2,4,4,Strong
4,5,1,Strong
4,5,2,Strong
3,3,2,Strong
4,3,1,Strong
5,6,3,Strong
4,3,1,Strong
5,5,5,Strong
3,6,7,Strong
3,5,3,Strong
3,4,1,Strong
2,8,2,Strong
2,6,6,Strong
3,6,2,Strong
3,4,3,Strong
4,5,1,Strong
3,5,1,Strong
4,3,2,Strong
3,1,1,Weak
2,1,1,Weak
3,1,1,Weak
2,4,1,Weak
2,1,1,Weak
3,1,1,Weak
3,1,1,Weak
2,4,1,Weak
3,1,1,Weak
3,1,1,Weak
2,5,1,Weak
3,2,1,Weak
3,3,1,Weak
2,1,1,Weak
3,3,1,Weak
2,1,1,Weak
2,1,1,Weak
2,1,1,Weak
```